# Determine Number of Executing/Pending SQL Queries in an Impala Admission Control Request Pool

Tags: hadoop-yarn, impala

I have a web front-end which submits an HPL/SQL job to a Linux server via SSH containing ImpalaSQL code which returns useful results. Our Impala Admission Control is limited to 5 concurrent running jobs. From the Linux command line, I'm trying to determine the number of executing/pending SQL queries running in a specific Impala Admission Control request pool. Knowing this number at any time will help our web front-end be more user friendly.

I tried to use the following code to view the running queries in a request pool, but unfortunately this is specific to YARN and not Impala Admission Control:

```
 yarn application -list -appStates RUNNING -queue my_request_pool
```

I did several Google searches, but was unable to find the corresponding command line for Impala Admission Control.

Does anyone know if there exists a CLI for Impala Admission Control so I can see the currently running/pending queries?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try accessing Web UI of the Impala daemons in your cluster. Among other things, it contains the lists of all running and X most recently completed queries. Default URL for it is `https://your.impala.host:25000/queries`. These lists contain "Resource pool" attribute which specifies the AC pool through which a query has entered.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  I am aware of the Web UI and I actually created a single all-encompassing web page which brings together all of the Web UI pages for all of our Impala hosts from port 25000. The users find this display very useful, but I was hoping for something built-in to Impala which returns single number for a specified resource pool rather than scraping web pages.  Thanks again!

Comment: Unlike Yarn's RM, there is no one single admission controller in Impala cluster (https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_admission.html#admission_architecture). Hence I'm afraid we are expected to do some level of aggregation ourselves. The only alternative to impalad web ui for this information I'm aware of is Cloudera Manager, and its API (https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v19/index.html) which somehow manages to expose `impala_admission_controller_local_num_admitted_running` timeseries.

Comment: I did by chance happen to find this on the InterWebs and am looking into this.  It seems promising!  Thanks, again, for you help!

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck!